# fancybox - how to scroll fancybox modal instead of page

Tags: jquery, scroll, fancybox

My fancybox modal's height exceeds that of the page. I know I can add a scroll bar within the modal itself, but that is not the solution I am looking for. Is it possible to scroll the modal with the page scroll bar so that I can see the hidden part of the modal?

Answer (score 0):

Either your target content has dimensions (`width` and `height`) or you set `width` and `height` as fancybox API options.

In any case, set `fitToView` to `false`

a). Content with dimensions

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false
});
```

b). Set dimensions in fancybox

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false,
    width: 350, // or whatever
    height: 1000 // height longer than the viewport
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7vZCf/)</kbd>